# Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set

Tags: theme, magento2.2.4

I am unable to apply a new theme in a clean install of 2.2.4. Upading to 2.2.5 does not fix the problem.

Comment: could please share with me what have you actually done

Comment: Hello @SwapnilTatkondawar, As per your instructions i have D/L the patch... but where do i install it on my IDE before running the said command? Thank you,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147642)

Comment: If i can't ask on an existing question would you like me to create a duplicate?

Comment: Please add comment instead of adding it as an answer.

Comment: Hello @SukumarGorai, I can't don't have enough reputation... Since you are speaking with me.... can you help with my concern?

Comment: Now check you can now add comment.

Comment: It still wont let me

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Note : This is a know issue in Magento 2.2.4 ([see GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968)) and below fix is just a temp fix. You should not directly change the Magento core file (override or create a plugin)**

Change in `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php` this:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if ($this->area) {
        throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
    }
    $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    return $this;
}
```

For this:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It should fix the issue

**Update** : can also be fixed by applying this [Patch](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2224)

Comment: Thanks! This has solved my issue. To reproduce: In Content > Design > Configuration > "Edit" your theme on Store View Level. If you do any change (no matter if applying a theme or changing a logo) the following message pops up: "Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set [on hold]".

Comment: It worked as i edited in core file. How to override this specifc model file so i dont edit any core file. What is the folder structure i need to use in app folder.

Comment: This worked for me too when I edited in core file.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Have you figured out how to override the core file? I want to do the same, but don't know how to override this core template file.

Comment: Sorry. No. Convinced client to go with wordpress. :)

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't do hotfix releases, unfortunately. However, they've released an official patch over here: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download (search for MAGETWO-93036).

Apply this patch by using below command

patch -p1 < m2-hotfixes/EE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-07-16.patch.

After applying mention patch and It works perfectly.

Comment: Issue resolved in Magento2.2.6

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with the link to the patch file :)

Comment: hi @Vishwas, this issue still exist in magento 2.3. I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

For fixed error `Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set` while saving theme configuration. You want create plugin for override `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php` file in custom module. And update `setForcedArea()` function.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AreaConfigFix/registration.php

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_AreaConfigFix', __DIR__);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AreaConfigFix/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_AreaConfigFix" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Email"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AreaConfigFix/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate">
        <plugin name="email_setforced_area" type="Vendor\AreaConfigFix\Plugin\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/AreaConfigFix/Plugin/Email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\AreaConfigFix\Plugin\Email\Model;

class AbstractTemplate
{
    private $emailConfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config $emailConfig)
    {
        $this->emailConfig = $emailConfig;
    }

    public function aroundSetForcedArea(\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate $subject, \Closure $proceed, $templateId)
    {
        if (!isset($this->area)) {
            $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the patch given by magento or changing the core files directly here is how I did it:

"File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ThemeErrorFix/registration.php"

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_ThemeErrorFix', __DIR__);
```

"File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ThemeErrorFix/etc/module.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ThemeErrorFix" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Email"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

"File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ThemeErrorFix/etc/di.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
        type="email_setforced_area" type="Vendor\ThemeErrorFix\Model\Template" />

</config>
```

"File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ThemeErrorFix/Model/Template.php"

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ThemeErrorFix\Model;

use Magento\Email\Model\Template as coreTemplate;

class Template extends coreTemplate

{
   public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code by removing the duplicated type attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Email\Model\Template"
        type="Vendor\ThemeErrorFix\Model\Template" />

</config>
```