# Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set magento 2.3

Tags: save, custom-theme, logo

> I am facing this error in version magento 2.3 while saving header logo.
>
> Actually this issue is resolved as per gihub but even it is coming.[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225628/something-went-wrong-while-saving-this-configuration-area-is-already-set)

Comment: You might get issue because of fileUploader, Check this url for more information: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa/252911#252911

Answer (score 0):

When you change in `vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php` this:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
if ($this->area) {
throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
}
$this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
return $this;
}
```

To:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
if (!isset($this->area)) {
$this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
}
return $this;
}
```

It will work.

Comment: it is already resolved in magento 2.3

Comment: Ok. But double check it.

Comment: this code is not there

Comment: Ok. Thats the issue.